# Unsigned short * argument called by reference - alternative in python for Cython code

Tags: python, c, cython, wrapper

I am a beginner in Python. I am currently writing python wrappers for some c code using Cython.

The c function header is :

```c
FunctionName (unsigned short *inputData, unsigned short *outputData)
```

inputData/outputData are arrays of unsigned short called by reference in the function.

---

I tried the following wrapper:

test.py

```
cdef extern from "Header.h":
void FunctionName (unsigned short *inputData, unsigned short *outputData)

def py_FunctionName(inputData, outputData)-> None :
FunctionName (inputData, outputData)
```

---

I am getting the following error when I run make:

```
  inputData,
       ^
Cannot convert Python object to 'unsigned short *'

 outputData,
       ^
Cannot convert Python object to 'unsigned short *'
```

---

I have tried the same code with (unsigned char *) and others and it compiled well

---

I would like to know the best way to solve this problem.
i.e.: writing a python function arguments who are pointers to arrays of type (equivalent to) unsigned short and can be changed inside the code similar to "by reference" in C?

And if not possible to do it directly, what are valid solutions in python?
I am currently using Python 3.8

Thank you.

Comment: All python arrays and lists, like other mutable objects, are passed "by reference". You call `somefunc(array1, array2)` and both array1 and array2 can be modified by somefunc, _always_. I'm not sure there exists an actual problem that needs to be solved here.

Comment: (If you're asking not how to write that _in Python_, but how to write it _in Cython_, then that calls for a pointer to the MemoryView documentation).

Comment: ...that said, a Cython MemoryView is like any other mutable object in Python -- it's _always_ passed by reference.

Comment: Thank you Charles, it answered the most part of my question. Thank for bearing for my novicity.  The final part for me is how to define the unsigned short type.  I have modified the question to include more details. I tried naive steps which produced some error (included in the edited answer)

Comment: Thank you -- editing to include those details goes a long way to make this question answerable; I've retracted my close vote. Hopefully someone with more Cython background can step in -- it's been a lot of years since I used it last, and I've forgotten most of what I once knew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing from Cython to SWIG.
SWIG created the "c wrapper for python" on Debian in a straightforward way and identified all the data types without any errors.

I still don't know how to solve this for Cython. But - in my case - SWIG did the job.